Keras/TensorFlow: How to avoid the "OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: Iterating over a symbolic `tf.Tensor` is not allowed."-Error
I'm using Keras 3/TensorFlow 2.16.1 and would like to implement this example (https://keras.io/examples/vision/semisupervised_simclr/) for semi-supervised image classification using contrastive pretraining for 3D-data instead of 2D-images.
After adjusting the code from https://keras.io/examples/vision/semisupervised_simclr/ I get this error-message:
OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: Iterating over a symbolic tf.Tensor is not allowed. You can attempt the following resolutions to the problem: If you are running in Graph mode, use Eager execution mode or decorate this function with @tf.function. If you are using AutoGraph, you can try decorating this function with @tf.function. If that does not work, then you may be using an unsupported feature or your source code may not be visible to AutoGraph. See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/autograph/g3doc/reference/limitations.md#access-to-source-code for more information.
This is my mini-code-example:
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers, utils
import math

dataset_list = []

for i in range(0,100):
    array = np.random.random((10,10,10))
    dataset_list.append(array)

data = np.asarray(dataset_list)
label = np.random.randint(2, size=100)

def prepare_dataset(data, labels, batch_size):
    dataset_size = len(data)
    steps_per_epoch = dataset_size // batch_size

    train_size = int(0.8 * dataset_size)
    train_data, train_labels = data[:train_size], labels[:train_size]
    test_data, test_labels = data[train_size:], labels[train_size:]

    labeled_train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_data, train_labels))
    labeled_train_dataset = labeled_train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=dataset_size).batch(batch_size)

    unlabeled_train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_data)
    unlabeled_train_dataset = unlabeled_train_dataset.batch(batch_size).prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

    test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((test_data, test_labels))
    test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(batch_size).prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

    train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip(
        (unlabeled_train_dataset, labeled_train_dataset)
    ).prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

    return train_dataset, labeled_train_dataset, test_dataset

data = data.reshape(data.shape[0], data.shape[1], data.shape[2], data.shape[3], 1) # Adding a 1 for 1 Channel
train_dataset, labeled_train_dataset, test_dataset = prepare_dataset(data, label, 30)

def get_augmenter(min_area):
    zoom_factor = 1.0 - math.sqrt(min_area)
    return tf.keras.Sequential(
        [
            layers.Rescaling(1 / 255),
            layers.RandomFlip("horizontal"),
            layers.RandomTranslation(zoom_factor / 2, zoom_factor / 2),
            layers.RandomZoom((-zoom_factor, 0.0), (-zoom_factor, 0.0)),
            RandomGeometricTransform(),
        ]
    )

def get_encoder():
    return tensorflow.keras.Sequential(
        [
            layers.Conv3D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), activation="relu"),
            layers.MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2)),
            layers.Conv3D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), activation="relu"),
            layers.MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2)),
            layers.Dropout(0.5),
            layers.Flatten(),
            layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"),
            layers.Dropout(0.5),
            layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"),
        ],
        name="encoder",
    )
    
baseline_model = tensorflow.keras.Sequential(
    [
        get_encoder(),
    ],
    name="baseline_model",
)
baseline_model.compile(
    optimizer=tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate= 0.0001),
    loss="binary_crossentropy",
    metrics=["binary_accuracy"],
)

num_epochs = 20
batch_size = 525
width = 128
temperature = 0.1

contrastive_augmentation = {"min_area": 0.25}
classification_augmentation = {
    "min_area": 0.75,
}


class RandomGeometricTransform(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.seed_generator = tf.random.experimental.Generator.from_seed(1337)

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config()
        return config

    def call(self, images, training=True):
        if training:
            images = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(images, seed=self.seed_generator.make_seeds(2)[0][0])
        return images

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape


class ContrastiveModel(tensorflow.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.temperature = temperature
        self.contrastive_augmenter = get_augmenter(**contrastive_augmentation)
        self.classification_augmenter = get_augmenter(**classification_augmentation)
        self.encoder = get_encoder()
        self.projection_head = tensorflow.keras.Sequential(
            [
                tensorflow.keras.Input(shape=(width,)),
                layers.Dense(width, activation="relu"),
                layers.Dense(width),
            ],
            name="projection_head",
        )
        # Single dense layer for linear probing
        self.linear_probe = tensorflow.keras.Sequential(
            [layers.Input(shape=(width,)), layers.Dense(10)],
            name="linear_probe",
        )

    def compile(self, contrastive_optimizer, probe_optimizer, **kwargs):
        super().compile(**kwargs)

        self.contrastive_optimizer = contrastive_optimizer
        self.probe_optimizer = probe_optimizer

        self.probe_loss = tensorflow.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

        self.contrastive_loss_tracker = tensorflow.keras.metrics.Mean(name="c_loss")
        self.contrastive_accuracy = tensorflow.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy(
            name="c_acc"
        )
        self.probe_loss_tracker = tensorflow.keras.metrics.Mean(name="p_loss")
        self.probe_accuracy = tensorflow.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy(name="p_acc")

    @property
    def metrics(self):
        return [
            self.contrastive_loss_tracker,
            self.contrastive_accuracy,
            self.probe_loss_tracker,
            self.probe_accuracy,
        ]

    def contrastive_loss(self, projections_1, projections_2):
        projections_1 = ops.normalize(projections_1, axis=1)
        projections_2 = ops.normalize(projections_2, axis=1)
        similarities = (
            ops.matmul(projections_1, ops.transpose(projections_2)) / self.temperature
        )

        batch_size = ops.shape(projections_1)[0]
        contrastive_labels = ops.arange(batch_size)
        self.contrastive_accuracy.update_state(contrastive_labels, similarities)
        self.contrastive_accuracy.update_state(
            contrastive_labels, ops.transpose(similarities)
        )

        loss_1_2 = tensorflow.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(
            contrastive_labels, similarities, from_logits=True
        )
        loss_2_1 = tensorflow.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(
            contrastive_labels, ops.transpose(similarities), from_logits=True
        )
        return (loss_1_2 + loss_2_1) / 2

    def train_step(self, data):
        (unlabeled_images, _), (labeled_images, labels) = data
        # Both labeled and unlabeled images are used, without labels
        images = ops.concatenate((unlabeled_images, labeled_images), axis=0)
        # Each image is augmented twice, differently
        augmented_images_1 = self.contrastive_augmenter(images, training=True)
        augmented_images_2 = self.contrastive_augmenter(images, training=True)
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            features_1 = self.encoder(augmented_images_1, training=True)
            features_2 = self.encoder(augmented_images_2, training=True)
            projections_1 = self.projection_head(features_1, training=True)
            projections_2 = self.projection_head(features_2, training=True)
            contrastive_loss = self.contrastive_loss(projections_1, projections_2)
        gradients = tape.gradient(
            contrastive_loss,
            self.encoder.trainable_weights + self.projection_head.trainable_weights,
        )
        self.contrastive_optimizer.apply_gradients(
            zip(
                gradients,
                self.encoder.trainable_weights + self.projection_head.trainable_weights,
            )
        )
        self.contrastive_loss_tracker.update_state(contrastive_loss)

        preprocessed_images = self.classification_augmenter(
            labeled_images, training=True
        )
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            features = self.encoder(preprocessed_images, training=False)
            class_logits = self.linear_probe(features, training=True)
            probe_loss = self.probe_loss(labels, class_logits)
        gradients = tape.gradient(probe_loss, self.linear_probe.trainable_weights)
        self.probe_optimizer.apply_gradients(
            zip(gradients, self.linear_probe.trainable_weights)
        )
        self.probe_loss_tracker.update_state(probe_loss)
        self.probe_accuracy.update_state(labels, class_logits)


    def test_step(self, data):
        labeled_images, labels = data

        preprocessed_images = self.classification_augmenter(
            labeled_images, training=False
        )
        features = self.encoder(preprocessed_images, training=False)
        class_logits = self.linear_probe(features, training=False)
        probe_loss = self.probe_loss(labels, class_logits)
        self.probe_loss_tracker.update_state(probe_loss)
        self.probe_accuracy.update_state(labels, class_logits)

pretraining_model = ContrastiveModel()
pretraining_model.compile(
    contrastive_optimizer=tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    probe_optimizer=tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
)


pretraining_history = pretraining_model.fit(
    labeled_train_dataset, epochs=num_epochs, validation_data=test_dataset
)

Do you have any idea, how to fix this? I would be very grateful for that!
